# Retrieving proxy settings from IE10 in Windows 8 Metro app

Tags: c#, windows, windows-runtime

I would like to retrieve proxy settings from IE10 from my Metro application but the WebRequest.GetSystemWebProxy method doesn't look to be available and I can't think of another way.

I have written an implementation of IWebProxy where all my proxy settings are hard coded but this is really just a work around.

My app is written in C#.

Trawling the web, this looks to be a common question with no definitive answer.

I'm developing my app behind an ISA server and I need to be able to authenticate against it.

This is my first post so apologies if I haven't supplied sufficient details.

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know, this is not possible (maybe in the RTM version).

Answer (score 0):

I think credentials are now to be stored in the Windows 8 Password Vault.  In the end, this is what I did and it seemed to work well.